# Search field is still populated with previous search value after refreshing the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activescaffold

I am using ActiveScaffold 3.2.3 and Rails 3.2 and ruby 1.9.3

1. Enter search team
2. Click Search - Results get displayed
3. Click Reset - list get reset but Search Field is still populated with previous search term (bug).
4. Refresh page - Search Field is still populated with previous search term and list is displaying according to the search term(bug)

Answer (score 0):

Reset button next to Search button just closes the search tab. To reset the list(all records) there is button in top-right(main box) with the label 'Click to reset'.